# Visual Studio Online references... migrating from .NET 2.0 to 4.5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

We are in the middle of an application upgrade.  We're moving our code from ASP.NET 2.0 (using VS 2k5) to ASP.NET 4.5 (using VS 2k13 w/ VSO).  So I'm trying to get my old project installed and set up.  We're creating a solution to hold all our our business object library projects and our two main projects (web application and web service).

In our old set up our web site was an actual IIS website project.  We're setting up now as a Web Project.  I have a bunch of 3rd party tools we're using.  We used to dump the .dll's into the BIN and go from there.  But I want ot set this up better than that.

Several project share the same DLLS.  I was thinking of creating a folder under the solution called IncludeLibraries and the putting all the DLLS in there.  Then referencing them from any project that needs them.  Browsing to that folder and selecting the DLL.  Everyone is developing locally now and I don't want the project not to build if the user doesn't have the exact same setup so trying to keep everything in TFS.  Does this sound right?

Also, we were using MS Web Service Extensions 3.0.  Am I going to have to install that/load DLL's?  Or is there a way for me to get around those moving to ASP.NET 4.5?

Answer (score 0):

You should move all of your reference assemblies to Nuget. You will likely find many of them already there, and you can create a local Nuget repository to manage the rest.

While it will take a little bit of setup, it should not take you longer than a day.

You will also need to migrate your Web Site to a Web Application. Web Sites have not been really supported for many years and you will not be able to take advantage of any if the modern techniques untill you upgrade.

You can upgrade in place, and if you fix your references with Nuget, you should be in a good place.

Comment: I did update my site to a web application.  I know I downloaded some packages using NuGet, I didn't realize I could have my own local repository.  I have some components that are not in there so I'll give that a try.